# Cambridge Advanced English certification, doubts about Reading pt. 6

Tags: exam-questions, reading

I am preparing for CAE exam and sometimes the Reading part 6 is obscure to me, even when I am provided with the correct solution.

For example take these extracts from [this practice](https://assets.cambridge.org/97811076/89589/excerpt/9781107689589_excerpt.pdf):

> **The role of advertising in society today**
>
> **A**
>
> Almost all public spaces
>   nowadays have advertisements in sight, and all forms of media, from
>   newspapers to the cinema to the Internet, are filled with adverts.
>   This all-pervasive presence reflects the value of advertising to us.
>   **Without it, businesses of all types and sizes would struggle to inform
>   potential customers about the products or services they provide, and
>   consumers would be unable to make informed assessments when looking
>   for products to buy and services to use. Without advertising, the
>   promotion of products and practices that contribute to our physical
>   and psychological well-being – medicines to treat minor ailments,
>   insurance schemes to protect us, clothes and cosmetics to make us look
>   and feel better – would be infinitely more problematic than it is**. And
>   without advertisements and the aspirations represented in them, the
>   world would be a far duller place.
>
> **B**
>
> Advertising is everywhere, and
>   it’s often so subtle that we don’t realise it’s there at some level of
>   our consciousness. The ultimate aim, of course, is to get us to buy
>   things, regardless of whether it makes sense for us to do so. **In fact,
>   adverts mostly impair rational decision-making**. A recent study in the
>   UK found that 90% of customers failed to understand the truth about
>   what was on offer in adverts for broadband internet services. This
>   irrational dimension is evident in the success advertisers enjoy not
>   only in getting us to buy products that, directly or indirectly, cause
>   physical damage to us, but also in raising our expectations about what
>   our lives should be like – expectations that inevitably imply
>   something is wrong with us if we don’t meet them. Having said this,
>   advertising is fundamental to the workings of modern economies, so the
>   chances are that it will only continue to grow in significance.
>
> **C**
>
> There is a tendency to underestimate people’s intelligence and to
>   invest advertising with powers it doesn’t have. Certain dubious
>   techniques have been banned – like the use of subliminal images shown
>   so quickly that viewers don’t consciously realise they’ve seen them –
>   but other forms of advertising are simply manifestations of
>   creativity. Audiences understand this and are able to enjoy adverts
>   without falling prey to some complex deception. **They know that an
>   advert tells them a product exists and suggests they might benefit
>   from having it**. They don’t expect it to provide objective details,
>   confirming why they should or should not go ahead with a purchase.
>   They are also smart enough to know that what they see in
>   advertisements is fiction and, therefore, not something they should
>   feel bad about if they don’t have it. The bottom line, however, is
>   that advertising helps the wheels of the economy to turn, a crucial
>   role which societies are likely to depend on for the foreseeable
>   future.
>
> **D**
>
> Advertising is a worldwide, multi-billion dollar industry
>   and inevitably tends to favour large businesses, which can afford
>   advertising costs, rather than smaller companies, which can’t. In that
>   way, it makes life ever more difficult for that sector of the economy
>   – small and medium-sized businesses – which is the key to a nation’s
>   prosperity. Advertising also encourages certain patterns of
>   consumption – fast food, cars, labour-saving devices and so on – which
>   characterise a sedentary lifestyle and undermine physical well-being,
>   while also generating a sense of inadequacy and unhappiness among
>   people who feel inferior if they don’t possess a product or conform to
>   certain ideas of what is ‘beautiful’ or ‘cool’. And **far from providing
>   consumers with clear, reliable information enabling them to make
>   sensible decisions about what to spend their money on, advertisers use
>   underhand methods to confuse and manipulate feelings and thoughts**.

Consider the question:

> Which contributor has a different opinion from the others on the extent to which advertising helps people to make choices?

The correct answer is **A** but I do not understand why. I highlighted the parts that for me are important for the question. **B** and **D** think adverts influence badly decision-making ("impair decision-making", "far from providing clear, reliable information"). **A** suggests that advertisement help customers to make informed assessment but so does **B** by saying "They know that an advert tells them a product exists and suggests they might benefit from having it".

Can someone help me understand why is **A** the correct answer?

Comment: A seems to think that advertising serves a useful function. B and D say that it misleads consumers, C says that consumers are intelligent enough _not_ to be misled - so there doesn't seem to me to be a 3 - 1 division.

Comment: @KateBunting so it is ambiguous for you too, isn't it?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

B and D are agreed that "adverts manipulate and do not help people to make decisions". These seem to be expressing a similar opinion.

C is saying that adverts are enjoyable but don't manipulate people.

A says that without adverts inform people and help them to make decisions.

So A is the only contributor that says that adverts help people to make a decision.

But the answer is unclear. Since C is the only contributor that says adverts have no effect. So either A or C would seem to be a defendable choice.

You don't seem to be missing anything, assuming anything that isn't given.